# GMaps API + Fusion Tables Stopped Working

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I have an application which uses the Google Maps API and fusion tables which stopped working as of today (the code and Fusion tables databases weren't changed and were working yesterday.) I have checked the error log and didn't see anything.

The page can be found at http://www2.ece.ohio-state.edu/~garryj/PassiveRadar/Passive%20Radar%20Coverage%20Tool.html

I was hoping someone with a better Javascript background and more experienced debugging skills than I could spot the error quickly, although the code is rather long.

All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does it work if you use the [release or the frozen versions of the API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics#Versioning)?

Answer (score 1):

it seems that google has updated the default.css, the prevoius version sets the height of `#map_canvas` **and** `#map-canvas`, the current only for `#map-canvas`.

Add this style to your page:

```
html, body, #map_canvas {
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
```

}

and remove the redundant

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css">
```

Comment: I added the extra style which worked a treat. I removed the bit you say is redundant, and the map no longer worked, so I'm not convinced that bit is valid, though? But the first bit definitely is, hence I gave your answer an upvote, since it allowed me to fix my map.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the styles for body + html, see my updated answer